# Oracle 10g/11g for Mac

Tags: sql, macos, oracle

I am trying to learn Oracle SQL with the help of the book 'Oracle SQL by Example' and it recommends that I download Oracle 11g to be able to take full advantage of what the book has on offer when it comes to practising the skills I learn.

However, Oracle's website seems not to offer 11g for Mac and I cannot find a link to 10g that is still valid (or, indeed, that doesn't dead end at the Oracle website). Does anyone have any suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest route might be to install [VirtualBox](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html) and one of the [pre-built VM images](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html) Oracle provides. It's simpler to get started than having to navigate the database software installation and DB creation, if you aren't interested in those aspects at the moment.

The Database App Development VM gives you a pre-installed database, plus SQL*Plus and SQL Developer to run examples and your own code as you learn.

Comment: *25 GB for download of zip files, 75GB for expanded VM image* - so enterprisy... love Oracle, you get what you pay for ))