# How to create a user in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: oracle

I am newbie to oracle sql developer 3.1.07.42, and have just installed it on my machine. I want to make a new connection, but it requires a user and a password which I do not know. I have been googling about it since many days, and have learned that there are some commands to create user, but I do not know where should I run those commands, because I cannot run queries/commands until the connection is created.
Would anyone let me know what should I do?

Comment: You need to install a database server.
Sql Developer is just a client application.

Comment: Okay thanks for your response. Actually I wanted to make dummy connection so I could run my own database.Anyhow,thank you.

Comment: You can't make a 'dummy' connection, you need a database first, and can then connect to that. It sounds like you might need to look at the [concepts guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/toc.htm) and other documentation. If you're just experimenting you could start with a pre-built test image; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13323669/266304) for more.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 19):

Steps for creating new user :

1)Open Sql Developer, make new connection.

2)Login with System username and password(made during installation).

3)Once you connect, expand the System user (under Connections, in the left pane) and scroll down to Other users. Then right click users and add new user.

4)Give its username and password & select appropriate system privilege.

5)You are done now, check by making new connection.

Comment: 3)Once you connect, Right click users and add new user.

I could connect oracle db with system username and pwd.

Where can I click right users and add new user?

Answer (score 3):

Use this below simple commands to create an user

```
-- Create a user
CREATE USER youruser IDENTIFIED BY yourpassword;
--Grant permissions
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, DBA TO demo;
```

Answer (score 1):

you should install database software in your local pc/laptop then create user in the database and you can connect the database via sql developer by key in username and password that already created.If you want to connect to other database same step like the previous step but before that you need to point to the remote database.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. This is what I actually want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I thinks you should use "Database Configuration Assistant" to create new database and U can set user name and password and use it in oracle SQL Developer!!!