# GRANT doesnt work in oracle SQL Developer 11g XE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Hi I installed Oracle SQL Developer 11g XE, I created a connection with my admin account, created some tables and I need to add a few users with various grants.

So I add new user like is write there [How to create a user in Oracle SQL developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791434/how-to-create-a-user-in-oracle-sql-developer)
I called "user1" and next in SQL editor I typed:

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO user1;
GRANT SELECT ON pracownik TO user1 WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

but when I logging as user1 and then type:

```
select * from pracownik;
```

I got an error:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
```

I dont know how to do it - also is weird for me that I cant add priviliges manually like is this shown in link above - I just have blank space.
[image]

Comment: you can create a synonym for schema.pracownik in user1's schema, then when they go to select from it, they don't need to include the schema name for pracownik to be foun

Comment: In what schema does the table PRACOWNIK exist? To find out execute `SELECT * FROM DBA_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PRACOWNIK'`. Then use `<owner>.PRACOWNIK` as the fully-qualified table name when retrieving data. Best of luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you have select privilege, you have to prefix the table name with the table owner `select * from <owner>.pracownik;`, where `<owner>` is the user name that own table.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add "<owner>." Also I resolved this problem by adding privileges manually from cetrain table - Grants->Privileges->Grant and then it works.