# How to install Oracle 12c or 11g on El capitan?

Tags: oracle, macos, oracle11g, osx-elcapitan, oracle12c

I've searched many places on the web. There is no clear solution on how to install Oracle 12c or 11g on Mac.

Anybody any success in installing that on Mac?

Comment: I don't think an installation on OS X  is supported at all. You can run it inside Linux on a virtual machine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827872/setting-up-the-oracle-database-on-macbook-pro-os-x-yosemite?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the solution.But VM's dry the battery very quickly. Is there any other alternative than  VMs????